# Joda Time - Day of month and Month of Year Not returning 2 digit output

Tags: java, jodatime

I have following code:

```
String dateUTC = "2013-09-08T10:23:54.663-04:00";
org.joda.time.DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(dateUTC);
System.out.println(" Year : " + dateTime.getYear());
System.out.println(" Month : " + dateTime.getMonthOfYear());
System.out.println(" Day : " + dateTime.getDayOfMonth()); 

The Output of this program is :
Year : 2013
Month : 9 // I want this to be 2 digit if the month is between 1 to 9
Day : 8 // I want this to be 2 digit if the month is between 1 to 9
```

Is there any way I can retrieve the value of month and year in 2 digit using Joda API.

Comment: _I want this to be 2 digit if the month is between 1 to 9_ How does that make sense?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis 01-09

Comment: I want the month as 09 and day as 08

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An alternative way would be using decimal formater

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
```

==========================================================================================

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
public class Collectionss {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
        org.joda.time.DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
        System.out.println(" Year : "+dateTime.getYear());      
        System.out.println(" Month : "+ df.format(dateTime.getMonthOfYear()));
        System.out.println(" Day : "+dateTime.getDayOfMonth()); 
    }

}
```

Comment: I will go with your solutions, looks easy and straightforward.

Comment: While this solution works, Reimeus's answer below is the correct one.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Thank you

Answer (score 40):

You can simply use [`AbstractDateTime#toString(String)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#toString(java.lang.String))

```
System.out.println(" Month : "+ dateTime.toString("MM"));
System.out.println(" Day : "+ dateTime.toString("dd"));
```

Comment: Simplest, most straight-forward answer.  Wish I'd thought of it! +1.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `getMonthOfYear()` - that just returns an `int`. What value could it possibly return for a month earlier than `October` which would satisfy you? To put it another way, let's take Joda Time out of the equation... what would you expect the output of this to be?

```
int month = 9;
System.out.println(" Month : " + month);
```

?

You need to understand the difference between *data* (an integer in this case) and the textual representation you want for that integer. If you want a specific format, I suggest you use [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). (It's very rarely a good idea to print out a single field at a time anyway... I would have expected you to want something like "2013-09-08" as a single string.)

You could also use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to control the output format, or `DecimalFormat`, or [`PrintStream.printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) - there are any number of ways of formatting integers. You need to understand that the number 9 is *just* the number 9 though - it doesn't have a format associated with it.

Comment: In this specific example he could even just `month<10 ? "0" : ""` the leading 0

Comment: @Cruncher: Yes, but I suspect that in the real requirements, using a `DateTimeFormatter` will be the way to go.

Comment: I hear you, But can I get and example using DateTimeFormatter which will return me the month and day in 2 digit format

Comment: @JavaCoder he linked the documentation

Comment: @JavaCoder: How about you try it first, and tell us what you've tried and what went wrong?

Comment: The Joda API should have overloaded methods which return String as well so that it can return 2 digit value, and then programmer use either of them  based on their requirement.

Comment: @JavaCoder DateTimeFormatter is in their API. There are so many different ways to format dates, it would be impractical to have an overload for all of them. So they use a formatter class.

Comment: @JavaCoder: No, it shouldn't, IMO. Single responsibility principle applies. A `DateTime` is responsible for telling you what the month is, etc - a formatter is responsible for formatting.

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.format("%tB %te, %tY%n", c, c, c); // -->  "September 10, 2013"
System.out.format("%tl:%tM %tp%n", c, c, c);  // -->  "01:59 pm"
System.out.format("%tD%n", c);    // -->  "09/10/13"
```